# Django sending message issue

Tags: django

I have a model called Message and this has a field called in_response_to . I use this field to identify which messages are related to each other by storing the primary key of the original message inside each related message and I list all the message

If I receive a new message from You and I wanted to reply . I would create a hidden_field under my textbox and store the new message primary id and use that to create a message by storing the primary key inside in_response_to so I know this message relate to that message and the method would repeat , so every message related will have the original primary key.

So its like

```
(1) =  message primary key
(s) =  store message primary key inside in_response_to

John(1) send mail to Peter(s)
Peter(1) send mail to John(s)
John(1) send mail to Peter(s)
```

Now the problem is , If I send you a message . The in_response_to is blank because its a new message . If you replied to that message , you would store my primary key inside in_response_to but when I try to reply again . I end up sending it to myself . I don't know why . Can someone please help me . I'm running in circles

The problem is here

```
        if messages.in_response_to:
            if messages.user !=   request.user:
                primary = messages.in_response_to 
                Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.user,body=body,in_response_to=primary)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
            if messages.user ==  request.user:
                Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.recipient.user,body=body,in_response_to=primary)

        Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.user,body=body,in_response_to=messages)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
```

models

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    in_response_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

views.py

```
 @login_required
 def read(request,id):
     try:
         messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id,recipient=request.user.id) 
     except Message.DoesNotExist:
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Display'))
     if request.method =='POST':
         form = NewMessageForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             id = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
             try:
                 messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id)
             except Message.DoesNotExist:
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:LoginRequest'))


             body = form.cleaned_data['body']
             if messages.in_response_to:
                 if messages.user !=   request.user:
                     primary = messages.in_response_to 
                     Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.user,body=body,in_response_to=primary)
                     return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))
                 if messages.user ==  request.user:
                     Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.recipient.user,body=body,in_response_to=primary)

             Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=messages.user,body=body,in_response_to=messages)
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:message'))

     if messages.in_response_to:
         m = messages.in_response_to.id
         message = Message.objects.filter(in_response_to=messages.in_response_to ).filter(created__lte=messages.created)

        initial = {}
         initial.update({'hidden_field': m})
         form = NewMessageForm(initial=initial)
         return render(request,'read.html',{'message':message,'form':form,'m':m})

     initial = {}
     initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})
     form = NewMessageForm(initial=initial)

     return render(request,'read.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form})

 @login_required
 def message(request):
     form = CheckBoxForm()

     messages = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user.id).order_by("-created")
     return render(request,'messages.html',{'messages':messages,'form':form})
```

template

{% csrf_token %}

```
{{form.body}}{{form.hidden_field}}
   <input type = "submit" value= "add" class="sen"/>

</form>
```

forms

```
class NewMessageForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=False,max_length=22000)
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())       
    class Meta:
        model = Message
```

Comment: Both Peter and John have the same ID?

Comment: @Neal  nope , they only store the original message primary key inside in_response_to to identify if the messages are related

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, you should understand that you may be victim hackers. If they will can changing `in_response_to` from `hidden input` it broke the chains of the messages.

Comment: I know they can tamper data but i think you can verify if the message is originally from the user